# Return Specific Content Type in Site Collection Using REST API

Tags: rest, client-object-model

I am looking for a way to use the REST API to return specific fields of a specific content type so that I can bind it to a table.

It seems the List API is used against a specific List but in my case I want to search all lists and return only a specific content type that I have defined in the site collection.  Additionally I want it to return 4 specific fields of that content type so I can bind it to a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Search API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx) with a property restriction of

```
 ContentType:[Your_CTYPE_Here]
```

Comment: But how do I get my 4 specific fields to also be returned?  I need to bind them all to a table.

Comment: Did you read the link I provided? The "SelectProperties" query parameter?

Answer (score 5):

### REST request to retrieve fields in Content Type

The following example demonstrates how to return all fields in `Task` Content Type:

```
/_api/web/contenttypes/getById('0x0108')/fields
```

### REST request to retrieve specific fields in Content Type

The following example demonstrates how to return `Title`, `AssignedTo`, `TaskDueDate` and `TaskStatus` fields in `Task` Content Type:

```
/_api/web/contenttypes/getById('0x0108')/fields?$filter=(InternalName eq 'Title') or (InternalName eq 'AssignedTo') or (InternalName eq 'TaskDueDate') or (InternalName eq 'TaskStatus')
```